# Set Builder Notation for Prime Numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I express the set of primes using set builder notation. The less words, the better!

I was thinking something along the lines of:
$P = \{x_i \mid x_j \equiv x_k \pmod\alpha \Rightarrow x_k = 1, \beta x_j; \; x_i > 1; \; i,j,k \in \mathbb{Z}^+; \; \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Translate your predicates into words and see if they make sense and capture primality,

Comment: The set you have written above gives you $\{x|x>1\}$. Also, it isn't true that a prime mod a number always has to give 1 or the prime. For example, $5(\mod 3)\equiv 2$.

Comment: How about: $$P=\{x\in\Bbb N:\forall a,b\in\Bbb N,ab\ne x\ne1\}$$

Comment: Less words might be better; but clear definitions are the best.

Comment: @columbus8myhw that makes no sense. Your $P$ is empty.

Comment: @user251257 Whoops.$$P=\{x\in\Bbb N:\forall a,b\in\Bbb N,(a+2)(b+2)\ne x\ne1\}$$This isn't the most elegant, but it's a short way to guarantee that the factors are at least $2$. (If you don't consider $0$ to be in $\Bbb N$, replace the $2$s with $1$s.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw: if you consider $0$ natural, then you should exclude $x=0$ :D

Comment: @user251257 $$P=\{x\in\Bbb N:\forall a,b\in\Bbb N,a=1\lor b=1\lor ab\ne x\ne1\}$$Mehhh

Comment: @BenS. Yeah I just corrected my post! Is it correct now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option: $$\left\{n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq2}: m\in\mathbb{Z}\wedge1<m<n\implies m\not\mid n\right\}$$
(the set of integers $n$ that are at least 2, such that whenever $m$ is an integer and $m$ is between 1 and $n$, then $m$ won't divide $n$)

or
$$\left\{n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq2}: m\mid n\implies |m|=1\vee|m|=n\right\}$$
(the set of integers $n$ that are at least 2, such that whenever $m$ divides $n$, it means that either $m$ is $1,-1,n$, or $-n$.)

Comment: Can you please "spell" this out like @Paul did in the case of his answer?

Comment: @JonathanPrescott OK

Comment: Thanks @alex.jordan. This is what I was looking for. Something very simple and concise!

Answer (score 2):

How about this? $$\{n\in\mathbf{Z} : \forall a,b \in \mathbf{Z},\, n\mid ab \Rightarrow n\mid a \vee n \mid b\}$$

Comment: What do you mean by $ab \Rightarrow n$ ?

Comment: @paul it reads $(n|ab) \implies (n|a \lor n|b)$!

Comment: It's good, but technically, $1$, $0$, $-1$, or any negative of a prime meet this too. That's why I went with $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq2}$ in mine.

Answer (score 1):

$$P = \{n \in \mathbb{N}_{\gt 1}\mid  (n-1)! \equiv -1 \bmod{n}\}$$
[Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem)

Answer (score 0):

$$P = \{x \in \mathbb{Z} \;| \;\;\; [\;\neg\exists y\in\mathbb{Z} : {\;\;\;\;(x \mod y  = 0)};  \;\; 1<|y|<|x|)\;] \;; \;|x| \neq1\;\}$$

{$x$ belonging to the Integers | No Integer (whose absolute value is between 1 and the absolute value of x) should leave a remainder when $x$ is divided by it; x is not 1 or -1}

Comment: Shouldn't we have $x \in \mathbb{N}$ instead?

Comment: There are negative primes as well that should be taken into account

Comment: But if you want to account for only the positive primes, then yes, and then you could also leave out the absolute values